# Write a matrix to a txt file without getting extra 0 values

Tags: matlab, matrix, text-files

I'm trying to write a matrix to a txt file. I've managed to do that but I don't want to include any `0` in my txt file.

My matrix looks like this:

```
5 0 0; 1 2 28; 1 3 60; 1 4 100; 1 5 108; 2 3 48; 2 4 83; 2 5 90; 3 4 41; 3 5 46; 4 5 12
```

And I would like the output in my txt file to look like this:

```
5; 1 2 28; 1 3 60; 1 4 100; 1 5 108; 2 3 48; 2 4 83; 2 5 90; 3 4 41; 3 5 46; 4 5 12
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What comes to mind is: convert every row of the array into a cell, then remove all zeros using `cellfun`, then `sprintf` the cell and save the result to a file.

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
%Given matrix is:
matrix= [5 0 0; 1 2 28; 1 3 60; 1 4 100; 1 5 108; 2 3 48; 2 4 83; 2 5 90; ...
    3 4 41; 3 5 46; 4 5 12];

%Converting the matrix into a string and doing some adjustements
out=regexprep(mat2str(matrix),';','; ');  
out=regexprep([' ',out(2:end-1)],' 0',''); % Now Removing zeros

fid=fopen('MyFile.txt','w+'); %Creating a file
%If your path is not set, either set it or give the full path in the above line 
% like this, for example: 'D:\Assignment\MyFile.txt'
fprintf(fid, out(2:end));  %Writing data to the text file (excluding the added space)
fclose(fid);               %Closing the text file
```

Read the documentation of [**`mat2str`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html),  [**`regexprep`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), [**`fopen`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), [**`fprintf`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html), and [**`fclose`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) for details of these functions.

---

**Output:**

[image: output]